# Is there a reason Ruby 1.8.7 is still so widely used?

Tags: ruby

I repeatedly see Ruby 1.8.7 still widely used for many situations, and even here on SO, where people show a stack-trace, indicating they are running 1.8.7, and lots of modern projects that strive to maintain backwards compatibility with that version. I often wonder why.

1.8.7 was a good, stable release, but there was nothing particularly special about it, other than it was the current version around a popularity peak for the language. The 1.9 versions offered many optimizations without breaking anything (that I am aware of) from the 1.8 versions, and was equally stable, so I would even understand still using 1.9.3 for older versions. But why 1.8.7? Is there some reason?

There were some wider sweeping changes with the release of 2.0, and more care had to be taken to maintain compatibility with previous versions from it. Why use 1.8.7? It retired on June 30, 2013, yet still we see it.

Is there any particular reason for this, or is it simply preference? Is it related to Rails compatibility?

I am not making the claim that 1.8.7 is still some hugely popular version. I am stating that it is more widely used than what would be expected to be the norm for a deprecated and outdated version, and inquiring into any known reason for that trend.

Comment: Could you provide more details to support your first paragraph? I haven't come across 1.8.7 in years, I can't remember the last time I saw it show up in a stack trace here, and I'm not aware of any projects that care about compatibility with 1.8.7.

Comment: I can show multiple post from this site just today if that would help. The questions aren't specifically related to 1.8.7, just observation that  the version they are using is.

Comment: Yes, that would help. Are you sure they're new questions rather than old ones that have shown up in the RSS feed due to recent activity?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference of a an actual new question, and one that receives new activity. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642764/how-to-find-which-gem-version-to-use-for-a-certain-ruby-version-or-rails-version) from two hours ago. I am not digging through every recent post to try and prove anything. There is a "above normal" amount (excluding "just preference"), and I did get an answer as to why from someone who knew, but thank you. ;)

Comment: Sorry but "one" doesn't really count as "above normal". I ask for evidence and numbers to avoid bias in your memory. Human memory is not that reliable and subject to confirmation bias.

Comment: Feel free to dig through RECENT posts, or simply start paying attention yourself. from this point forward. No rudeness intended, by I am not wasting my time to dig through every recent post to prove the relevance of a question to one person when it has already been acknowledged and answered with sound reasoning. Please see the accepted answer if you would like to learn more.

Comment: Your claim that 1.9 didn't break anything from the 1.8 is not correct. That change was the largest of all updates, larger than the shift from 1.9 to 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding was that the 1.8.7 to 1.9.x transition broke rails and thus broke a lot of web sites.

As a result of this, many of those web sites stayed with Ruby 1.8.7 and (I'm less sure about this) Rails 3.x

This traumatic transition has been referenced by Matz and many others at various Ruby conferences over the years. It is used to underline the commitment of the Ruby development team to avoid ever doing that again.

Sorry, I don't have a reference for any of these videos.

Comment: That helps me understand it. As I stated, I am not a Rails user, so I did wonder if it was somehow related to Rails. Might be obvious to a Rails user, but if you don't know, you don't know, lol.

Comment: This just in. At a recent conference Matz discussed the future of Ruby. Around minute 34-35 he mentions the need to avoid big gaps like 1,8 to 1.9. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTNC26BtRFc#t=0m20s

Answer (score 1):

I would err on the side of caution when thinking it's widely used. It's most likely just more noticeable when you see a post asking about 1.8 or 1.9 stuff.

There's no better reason than it's just legacy stuff from when Rails was really, really hot — see: *new*. I would assume that people plucking around legacy stuff these days are relatively unfamiliar with Ruby, and are still hopping around on Rails 3 — and, admittedly, Rails 3 isn't vastly different than Rails 4 and Rails 5, but is vastly different from Rails 2.

Comment: Perhaps "widely used" is a misnomer, but more widely used than what I would consider even close to "normal" amount for a version so far outdated and deprecated. Thanks for the feedback, though. :)